# How to stream M4A files correctly?

Tags: javascript, audio, ffmpeg, streaming, html5-audio

I would like to stream an **M4A** audio file but for some reason the player starts to play the song only after downloaded the entire file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="https://php-test-easybreazy.c9users.io/music/1021785690_1171244514_239291028.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

In my **Ubuntu** server I used **FFMPEG** to encode my audio file.

The only thing I can think of is a metadata/encode issue.

**Why the player starts playing only after downloaded the entire file audio?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `-movflags +faststart` when encoding to MP4/M4V/M4A, or re-mux using this option:

```
ffmpeg -i input.m4a -c copy -movflags +faststart output.m4a
```